# How to write Yes command as a answer to this question? Thanks

Tags: windows, powershell, anaconda, chocolatey, openai-api

I am absolute beginner in coding. I took code from ChatGPT to install Anaconda. However, I stuck at last step. I tried almost all possible variants of yes. Could sb help me, pls? How I can write yes to last question? Thanks.

```
anaconda3 v2022.10 [Approved]
anaconda3 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package anaconda3 wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint):
```

Answer (score 3):

- To **answer an *interactive prompt*** that is being displayed by [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), type the letter enclosed in `[...]` that corresponds to the desired option, which in your case is `y` (for `[Y]es`), or - to also auto-confirm *subsequent* prompts, if any, during the installation at hand - `a` (for `[A]ll - yes to all`).
  Case doesn't matter.
  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit your choice.
- To ***suppress* (conceptually: auto-confirm) confirmation prompts**, follow the guidance in the note you cite:

  - For a *given installation command*, add the `-y` option on its command line.
  - To *persistently* suppress confirmation prompts, for *all* future Chocolatey installation commands, run the following *one-time* command, from an *elevated* session (run as administrator):

    - `choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation`